# Bitcoin transaction confirmed and spend but not funds recieved

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

Transaction id 
2d581849f11fd34a7d82a6913f78eaf19802bcd0c20aca5905f0d9aeab5f0832

Can someone plz advise what's the status

Comment: This transaction has 1204 confirmations, as of this writing. Is there something more specific that you would like to ask about this transaction?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it)

Comment: as Tony says, the tx is confirmed (visible in the blockchain). So if you haven't received the funds, you must try to contact the sender. There is little we can do here.

Answer (score 1):

As per the transaction id you have given, you can see the status here:

https://blockchain.info/tx/2d581849f11fd34a7d82a6913f78eaf19802bcd0c20aca5905f0d9aeab5f0832

And you can see that the transaction is complete, infact you have used the funds already.